# Upload photo to Picasa Web albums using HTTP post async in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, http-post, win-universal-app, httpclient, windows-10

I want to upload an image to the default Dropbox album of a user in Picasa Web albums. How do I do this in visual studio 2015?

I am able to select an image file using file picker and convert that to an IInputStream but I don't know how to add this stream to the Windows.Web.Http.httpclient's body.

Comment: You'll need to know if Picasa Web albums has a public API.  Their API should tell you what service to call, and how to structure your call into that service, including how to send your image to them.

Comment: Yes I know all of that. My question is how to add that inputstream to the post async requests body